# What's the annotation for "Produces" in Swagger annotations and OpenAPI v3.0?

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-php

On OpenAPI v2.0 and Swagger PHP the annotation for Produces was:

```
 /**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *      path="/posts",
 *      operationId="getPosts",
 *      tags={"Authentication"},
 *      produces="application/json"
 *      summary="Returns the posts",
 *      description="Returns the posts",
 *      @SWG\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="Successful operation"
 *      ),
 * )
 */
```

But On OpenAPI v3.0 and Swagger PHP I cannot find on how to annotate the *produces* on the documentation it states the it is now an attribute of the response `@OA\Response` but I can not find an example I already try just putting `"content" = "application/json"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define all the possible response content types for each `@OA\Response`.

E.g.:

```
     * @OA\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="successful operation",
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *             type="array",
     *             @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Pet")
     *         ),
     *         @OA\XmlContent(
     *             type="array",
     *             @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Pet")
     *         )
     *     ),
```

If your endpoint only generates JSON content, only define the entry for `@OA\JsonContent`.

See the full example [here](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore-3.0/controllers/Pet.php).